# Firefox Extension Content Script Invocation/Lifecycle

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I created a simple firefox add-on with the add-on SDK as below, but it only ever works once. I am using version 1.8 of the Add-On SDK.

```
$ mkdir test_ext
$ cd test_ext
$ cfx init
$ cat >package.json
  { 
  "name": "no2", 
  "license": "MPL 2.0", 
  "author": "", 
  "version": "0.1", 
  "fullName": "test_ext", 
  "id": "my-id", 
  "description": "a basic add-on"
  }
 $ cat >lib/main.js
   <!-- language: lang-js -->
   require("page-mod").PageMod({
      include: ["*.org"],
      contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
         '"<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";'
   });
 $ cfx run
```

Now in the browser if I go to w3.org it works. If I reload or go to a different .org domain like wwf.org nothing happens. How can I make it test and apply any new page?

Comment: I tested your PageMod code alone in the main.js and it worked in any .org site (including w3 and wwf). Using SDK 1.8 on the builder site.

Comment: It only works a single time for, I have to kill the browser spawned with 'cfx run' and run 'cfx run' again to make it work again,

Comment: Seems to work fine, Add-on SDK 1.12, Firefox 14.0.1 on Xubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would write this is:

```
require("page-mod").PageMod({
  include: ["*.co.uk"],
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
             '"<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";'
});
```

I think the problem with your code is the use of the 'new' keyword?

Comment: didn't fix it, described the scenario more in detail.